# Sending an ethernet connection over wireless

Tags: networking, windows-10, wireless-networking, ethernet

So I have two connections on my PC, and ethernet and a wireless one. My ethernet is connected to the internet and my wireless isn't connected to any network. I want to send my ethernet connection over my wireless card so I can use my ethernet connection through wireless.

I've tried the hosted network over windows but it hasn't worked as it requires the wireless card to have a connection to a network.

Is there anyway to do this on windows 10?

Comment: If I'm understanding you correctly, you are looking to allow other devices to connect to the internet by way of your wireless card in order to make use of the internet connection from your Ethernet nic. If that is the case, the feature you're looking for is Internet Connection Sharing (note that this will not work exactly like a wireless router will). It is better, if at all possible, to just invest in a router w/access point for this feature.

Comment: I am unable to get this working, as when I share my connection using my wireless card it disconnects my ethernet connection. Are you able to provide me with some steps?

Comment: @John Can you walk us through exactly how you tried to set up ICS and exactly how it went wrong? For example, "disconnects my ethernet connection" is ambiguous. Does that mean you lost the link? Couldn't reach the router? Couldn't reach the Internet? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

Most windows 10 laptops have a wireless hotspot feature located in the network tab (where you can see SSID's of networks), but you could get a program like Connectify to make a hotspot.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way:

Turn your Windows 10 PC into a mobile hotspot by sharing your Internet connection with other devices over Wi-Fi. You can share a Wi-Fi, Ethernet, or cellular data connection. If your PC has a cellular data connection and you share it, it will use data from your data plan.

Select the Start  button, then select **Settings  > Network & Internet > Mobile hotspot**.

For **Share my Internet connection from**, choose the Internet connection you want to share.

Select **Edit** > enter a new network name and password > **Save**.

Turn on **Share my Internet connection with other devices**.

To connect on the other device, go to the Wi-Fi settings on that device, find your network name, select it, enter the password, and then connect.

[image]